# How to attach file to mail from iPhone directory swift

Tags: iphone, swift, email

I'm new to iOS Development

Is it possible to attach a file from the folder of the iPhone/iPad device to the mail composer using swift? I've already made a mail composer, and there we can add the attachment. My question is how can we select and add the attachment from the memory of the device? Any help is appreciated
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What you have tried ? The file is available in the documents folder of your application ?

Comment: Is it an image that you want to attach?

Comment: I want  to fetch any type of file from the directory of the device. Any type of attachment(doc, pdf, jpeg.........)

Comment: The file may be in any folder in the documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
func sendMailWithFile(filePath: String) {

  if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
    let composer = MFMailComposeViewController()
    composer.setToRecipients(["mailid"])
    composer.setMessageBody("Body", isHTML: false)
    composer.setSubject("Subject")
    let attachmentData = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath)
    let mimetype = self.mimeTypefrom(filePath)
    composer.addAttachmentData(attachmentData!, mimeType: mimetype, fileName: filePath.lastPathComponent)
    self.presentViewController(composer, animated: true, completion: nil)
  } else {
    let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Check your mail configurations", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    sendMailErrorAlert.show()
  } 
} 

func mimeTypefrom(filePath: String) -> String {

    let fileExtension = filePath.pathExtension;
    let UTI =  UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, fileExtension, nil)
    let mimeType = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(UTI!.takeUnretainedValue(), kUTTagClassMIMEType);
    return (mimeType?.takeRetainedValue())! as String
}
```

**Note:** nill check not done for optionals.

**EDIT:** Added method mimeTypefrom

Comment: Your answer is close to the question, but not exact. It shows the error 'ViewController does not have a member named 'mimeTypefrom''

Comment: Use of unresolved Identifier 'UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag'. There is error in the following lines also. Do I need to import anything.

Comment: import MobileCoreServices
add this import statement

Comment: I am getting some runtime errors coz of nil values. U juz gave me d answer for fetching from a particular folder. I was searching to fetch a file from something like a file explorer. But, apple's privacy don't allow me.

Comment: In your code check the given filler is nil or not. Then check whether system can understand its type, if not, disable attaching code

Comment: The filler will be nil only if the directory does not have a file. I know my requirement is quite stupid in the case of iOS.